# Echo multiple variables from json

Tags: json

```
$api_url='https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price? 
fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR,AUD,GBP';

//{"USD":9662.45,"EUR":8049.92,"AUD":12792.38,"GBP":6998.2}

$cryptocurrency = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url));

$priceUSD = (float) $cryptocurrency->USD;

$priceAUD = (float) $cryptocurrency->AUD;

$priceEUR = (float) $cryptocurrency->EUR;

$priceGBP = (float) $cryptocurrency->GBP;

 echo  'BTC<br>';
 echo  $priceUSD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceAUD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceEUR.'<br>';
 echo  $priceGBP.'<br>';
```

The above code works with variable **fsym=BTC**

I need to request with **fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH**  and echo as the below example

```
$api_url='https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti? 
fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH&tsyms=USD,EUR,AUD,GBP';

//{"BTC":{"USD":9665.27,"EUR":8055.28,"AUD":12763.35,"GBP":6980.47},"ETH": 
{"USD":778.56,"EUR":648.67,"AUD":1030.77,"GBP":563.6},"DASH": 
{"USD":494.95,"EUR":410.57,"AUD":653.61,"GBP":357.47}}


$cryptocurrency = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url));

$priceUSD = (float) $cryptocurrency->USD;

$priceAUD = (float) $cryptocurrency->AUD;

$priceEUR = (float) $cryptocurrency->EUR;

$priceGBP = (float) $cryptocurrency->GBP;

 echo  'BTC<br>';
 echo  $priceUSD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceAUD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceEUR.'<br>';
 echo  $priceGBP.'<br>';

 echo  'ETH<br>';
 echo  $priceUSD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceAUD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceEUR.'<br>';
 echo  $priceGBP.'<br>';

 echo  'DASH<br>';
 echo  $priceUSD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceAUD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceEUR.'<br>';
 echo  $priceGBP.'<br>';
```

My code does not work because I have been unsuccessful with any code I have tried. I assume I need some foreach code but could not work out how to implement. Any guidance would be most appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP

$api_url='https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH&tsyms=USD,EUR,AUD,GBP';


$cryptocurrency = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url));


foreach($cryptocurrency as $key => $value)
{
$priceUSD = (float) $cryptocurrency->$key->USD;

$priceAUD = (float) $cryptocurrency->$key->AUD;

$priceEUR = (float) $cryptocurrency->$key->EUR;

$priceGBP = (float) $cryptocurrency->$key->GBP;

 echo  "$key<br>";
 echo  $priceUSD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceAUD.'<br>';
 echo  $priceEUR.'<br>';
 echo  $priceGBP.'<br>';

}
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php